# How to use mgrid to interpolate between a rectangle and a circle

Tags: python, numpy, math, pyvista

I am trying to create a 3D surface that has a 1/4 rectangle for the exterior and 1/4 circle for the interior. I had help before to create the 3D surface with an ellipse as an exterior but I cannot do this for a rectangle for some reason. I have done the math by hand which makes sense, but my code does not. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# parameters for the waveguide
# diameter of the inner circle
waveguide_throat = 30
# axes of the outer ellipse
ellipse_x = 250
ellipse_y = 170
# shape parameters for the z profile
depth_factor = 4
angle_factor = 40
# number of grid points in radial and angular direction
array_length = 100

phase_plug = 0
phase_plug_dia = 20
plug_offset = 5
dome_dia = 28
# theta is angle where x and y intersect
theta = np.arctan(ellipse_x / ellipse_y)
# chi is for x direction and lhi is for y direction
chi = np.linspace(0, theta, 100)
lhi = np.linspace(theta, np.pi/2, 100)

# mgrid to create structured grid
r, phi = np.mgrid[0:1:array_length*1j, 0:np.pi/2:array_length*1j]

# Rectangle exterior, circle interior 
x = (ellipse_y * np.tan(chi)) * r + ((waveguide_throat / 2 * (1 - r)) * np.cos(phi))
y = (ellipse_x / np.tan(lhi)) * r + ((waveguide_throat / 2 * (1 - r)) * np.sin(phi))


# compute z profile
angle_factor = angle_factor / 10000
z = (ellipse_x / 2 * r / angle_factor) ** (1 / depth_factor)

plotter = pv.Plotter()

waveguide_mesh = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
plotter.add_mesh(waveguide_mesh)
plotter.show()
```

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear interpolation you're trying to use is a general tool that should work (with one small caveat). So the issue is first with your rectangular edge.

Here's a sanity check which plots your interior and exterior lines:

```py
# debugging: plot interior and exterior
exterior_points = np.array([
    ellipse_y * np.tan(chi),
    ellipse_x / np.tan(lhi),
    np.zeros_like(chi)
]).T
phi_aux = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, array_length)
interior_points = np.array([
    waveguide_throat / 2 * np.cos(phi_aux),
    waveguide_throat / 2 * np.sin(phi_aux),
    np.zeros_like(phi_aux)
]).T
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pv.wrap(exterior_points))
plotter.add_mesh(pv.wrap(interior_points))
plotter.show()
```

[image: screenshot of the two edges: one semicircle and... another circular arc]

The bottom left is your interior circle, looks good. The top right is what's supposed to be a rectangle, but isn't.

To see why your original surface looks the way it does, we have to note one more thing (this is the small caveat I mentioned): the orientation of your curves is also the opposite. This implies that you interpolate the "top" (in the screenshot) point of your interior curve with the "bottom" point of the exterior curve. This explains the weird fan shape.

So you need to fix the exterior curve, and make sure the orientation of the two edges is the same. Note that you can just create the two 1d arrays for the two edges, and then interpolate them. You don't have to come up with a symbolic formula that you plug into the interpolation step. If you have 1d arrays of the same shape `x_interior, y_interior, x_exterior, y_exterior` then you can then do `x_exterior * r + x_interior * (1 - r)` and the same for `y`. This means removing the `mgrid` call, only using an array `r` of shape `(n, 1)`, and making use of array broadcasting to do the interpolation. This means doing `r = np.linspace(0, 1, array_length)[:, None]`.

So the question is how to define your rectangle. You need to have the same number of points on the rectangular curve than what you have on the circle (I would strongly recommend using the `array_length` parameter everywhere to ensure this!). Since you want to span the whole rectangle, I believe you have to choose an array index (i.e. a certain angle in the circular arc) which will map to the corner of the rectangle. Then it's a simple matter of varying only `y` for the points until that index, and `x` for the rest (or vice versa).

Here's what I mean: you know that the rectangle's corner is at angle `theta` in your code (although I think you have `x` and `y` mixed up if we assume the conventional relationship between "x", "y" and the tangent of the angle). Since `theta` goes from 0 to pi/2, and your `phi` values also go from 0 to pi/2, you should choose index `(array_length * (2*theta/np.pi)).round().astype(int) - 1` (or something similar) that will map to the rectangle's corner. If you have a square, this gives you `theta = pi/4`, and consequently `(array_length / 2).round().astype(int) - 1`. For `array_length = 3` this is index `(2 - 1) == 1`, which is the middle index for 3-length arrays. (The more points you have along the edge, the less it will matter if you commit an off-by-one error here.)

The only remaining complication then is that we have to explicitly broadcast the 1d `z` array to the common shape. And we can use the same math you used to get a rectangular edge that is equidistant in angles.

Your code fixed with this suggestion (note that I've added 1 to the corner index because I'm using it as a right-exclusive range index):

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# parameters for the waveguide
# diameter of the inner circle
waveguide_throat = 30
# axes of the outer ellipse
ellipse_x = 250
ellipse_y = 170
# shape parameters for the z profile
depth_factor = 4
angle_factor = 40
# number of grid points in radial and angular direction
array_length = 100

# quarter circle interior line
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, array_length)
x_interior = waveguide_throat / 2 * np.cos(phi)
y_interior = waveguide_throat / 2 * np.sin(phi)

# theta is angle where x and y intersect
theta = np.arctan2(ellipse_y, ellipse_x)
# find array index which maps to the corner of the rectangle
corner_index = (array_length * (2*theta/np.pi)).round().astype(int)
# construct rectangular coordinates manually
x_exterior = np.zeros_like(x_interior)
y_exterior = x_exterior.copy()
phi_aux = np.linspace(0, theta, corner_index)
x_exterior[:corner_index] = ellipse_x
y_exterior[:corner_index] = ellipse_x * np.tan(phi_aux)
phi_aux = np.linspace(np.pi/2, theta, array_length - corner_index, endpoint=False)[::-1]  # mind the reverse!
x_exterior[corner_index:] = ellipse_y / np.tan(phi_aux)
y_exterior[corner_index:] = ellipse_y

# interpolate between two curves
r = np.linspace(0, 1, array_length)[:, None]  # shape (array_length, 1) for broadcasting
x = x_exterior * r + x_interior * (1 - r)
y = y_exterior * r + y_interior * (1 - r)

# debugging: plot interior and exterior
exterior_points = np.array([
    x_exterior,
    y_exterior,
    np.zeros_like(x_exterior),
]).T
interior_points = np.array([
    x_interior,
    y_interior,
    np.zeros_like(x_interior),
]).T
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pv.wrap(exterior_points))
plotter.add_mesh(pv.wrap(interior_points))
plotter.show()

# compute z profile
angle_factor = angle_factor / 10000
z = (ellipse_x / 2 * r / angle_factor) ** (1 / depth_factor)
# explicitly broadcast to the shape of x and y
z = np.broadcast_to(z, x.shape)

plotter = pv.Plotter()

waveguide_mesh = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
plotter.add_mesh(waveguide_mesh, style='wireframe')
plotter.show()
```

The curves look reasonable:
[image: screenshot of fixed edges]

As does the interpolated surface:
[image: screenshot with wireframe of interpolated surface; lookin' good]

Comment: Andras, thank you! I see that I was trying to get too philosophical by trying to fit a formula that fit the last solution you gave me. Sometimes I take a solution and try to make it work with everything. Again, thank you for your help! If I have some more questions is it okay to comment on this thread?

Comment: @cwdesignsvs unless it's very specific to this answer you should come to [the Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) instead (just read the rules linked in the room's description). You can just ask your question there, or if you want you can ping me specifically, just make it clear in the message that I told you this is OK (we normally don't want users pinging random people, as you'll see in the rules) :)